# Making separate output files for every category in scrapy

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, export-to-csv

I tried to **scrape** yellow pages according to its categories. So i load categories from a text file and feed it to the start_urls. The problem i am facing here is saving the output separately for each category. Following is the code i tried to implement:

```
CATEGORIES = []
with open('Catergories.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

    for category in data:
        CATEGORIES.append(category.strip())
```

Opening the file in settings.py and making a list to access in the spider.

The spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from ..items import YellowItem
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings = get_project_settings()


class YpSpider(CrawlSpider):
    categories = settings.get('CATEGORIES')

    name = 'yp'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']

    start_urls = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms={0}&geo_location_terms=New%20York'
                      '%2C '
                      '%20NY'.format(*categories)]
    rules = (

        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="business-name"]', allow=''), callback='parse_item',
             follow=True),

        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="next ajax-page"]', allow=''),
             follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        categories = settings.get('CATEGORIES')
        print(categories)
        item = YellowItem()
        # for data in response.xpath('//section[@class="info"]'):
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
        item['phone'] = response.xpath('//p[@class="phone"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['street_address'] = response.xpath('//h2[@class="address"]/text()').extract_first()
        email = response.xpath('//a[@class="email-business"]/@href').extract_first()
        try:
            item['email'] = email.replace("mailto:", '')
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        item['website'] = response.xpath('//a[@class="primary-btn website-link"]/@href').extract_first()
        item['Description'] = response.xpath('//dd[@class="general-info"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['Hours'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="open-details"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()[not(ancestor::*['
                                       '@class="hour-category"])]').extract()
        item['Other_info'] = response.xpath(
            '//dd[@class="other-information"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()
        category_ha = response.xpath('//dd[@class="categories"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()
        item['Categories'] = " ".join(category_ha)
        item['Years_in_business'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="number"]/text()').extract_first()
        neighborhood = response.xpath('//dd[@class="neighborhoods"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()
        item['neighborhoods'] = ' '.join(neighborhood)
        item['other_links'] = response.xpath('//dd[@class="weblinks"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()').extract()

        item['category'] = '{0}'.format(*categories)

        return item
```

and here is the pipelines.py file:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings = get_project_settings()


class YellowPipeline(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.exporters = {}
        categories = settings.get('CATEGORIES')

        file = open('{0}.csv'.format(*categories), 'w+b')

        exporter = CsvItemExporter(file, encoding='cp1252')
        exporter.fields_to_export = ['title', 'phone', 'street_address', 'website', 'email', 'Description',
                                     'Hours', 'Other_info', 'Categories', 'Years_in_business', 'neighborhoods',
                                     'other_links']
        exporter.start_exporting()
        for category in categories:
            self.exporters[category] = exporter

    def spider_closed(self, spider):

        for exporter in iter(self.exporters.items()):
            exporter.finish_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        self.exporters[item['category']].export_item(item)
        return item
```

After running the code i get the following error:

```
exporter.finish_exporting()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'finish_exporting'
```

I need seperate csv file for each category. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the `iter()` in `iter(self.exporters.items())` ?

Comment: to iterate through dictionary items

Comment: In that case you don’t need the `iter()`.

Comment: throws unresolved reference error then....

Comment: When the only change is removing the `iter()` ?

Comment: yeah....but i managed to iterate without using iter()...but still am not getting the desired output

Comment: what is the problem with my solution?  You could even use a runner and listen for spider.finished signal and execute my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this in post-processing. Export all items to one .csv file with a category field. I think you are not thinking about this problem the right way and over complicating it. Not sure if this would even work but its worth a shot :)

```
with open('parent.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        with open('{}.csv'.format(row[category]), 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

You could apply this code using the spider closed signal as well.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed

Comment: hey i tried it and the thing is it does the job but there are some problems i am facing. it duplicated the data as well as it there is one space after every row. Moreover, i also want to use the same  headers used in the original csv. If u would kindly help with that i would be gratefull

Comment: someone please edit to use DictReader and also to write the header files. I no time atm

Comment: i have solved the other problem.. the only problem now is the headers. I can't figure out how to write them as due to for loop they come after every row as multiple csv files are being opened

Comment: use enumerate on reader... for idx, row in enumerate(reader):  then you can get the index of the list and only write headers for index 0

Comment: cool glad it finally worked out. if you wanted a more permanent solution you could look into the scrapy docs and create your own crawler running and attach this code to the spider.finished signal, but one time use or even a couple times I would just do it with this simple script rather than go to the trouble of making a modified runner.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.items()` returns iterable, each item in which looks like `tuple (key, value)` To get rid of this error you need to remove `iter` and unpack that items like `for category, exporter in self.exporter.items():`